# Where is the decision made on the default initial value for 'reduce'?

Tags: ruby

It appears to me that the default initial value for `reduce` is `0` when the operation is addition, and `1` for multiplication:

```
(5..10).reduce(:+) => 45
(5..10).reduce(0, :+) => 45

(5..10).reduce(:*) => 151200
(5..10).reduce(1, :*) => 151200
```

Where does Ruby make this decision? Looking at [enum.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a60a1c031e7fc1302db3cc8e415383231fa5870b/enum.c#L720), there isn't a traceable decision point like a lookup table that would infer the default initial value.

Comment: Just take a look at the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) next time: _"If you do not explicitly specify an **initial** value for **memo**, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of **memo**."_ ;-)

Comment: The original title of the post was modified, as well as the question content. IMO, this changes the question I originally asked, which was about the internals of Ruby. But, yes, fair enough.

Comment: I was referring to _"the default for addition is zero, and for multiplication, it is 1"_. The documentation reveals that this conclusion is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of an initial value, the first value of the array is used.  So there's no need to have an initial value as the operation will first be ran against the first two elements of the array (or Enumerable object).

Ultimately, if you look at Enum.c in the function `ary_inject_op` there's a piece of code:

```
if (init == Qundef) {
    v = RARRAY_AREF(ary, 0);
    i = 1;
    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) == 1)
        return v;
}
else {
    v = init;
    i = 0;
}
```

That's where the decision is made.  If `init` isn't defined, then the first element of the array is used as `v` (the accumulator) and `i` (the index) is moved ahead to 1.  If the total length of the array is 1, then the initial value is immediately returned.

On the other hand, if `init` is defined, then `v` is set to that value and `i` is set to 0 so that it'll later begin iteration on the first value in the array.

Comment: This was interesting for me, also, because it had never occurred to me that `inject` and friends weren't written in straight Ruby.